# pytube to download filtered video and audio together

Tags: python, pytube

I am using the simplest possible code to download bunch of youtube videos:

```
from pytube import YouTube

link=[
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Rb9CjDjqNC4", 
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pmmKCDvsFy8",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=erN1_QVCCM8",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=fjzM3NbgGzE", 
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JWBiY29GqRs",
  "https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=vp7zMFrHkmA"
]

for i in link: 
  s = YouTube(i)
  print(i)
  s.streams.filter(res="720p",mime_type="video/mp4").first().download()
```

But "strangely" videos don't have the sound. **When I remove filter sound is there, why?** I've looked online, but couldn't find any example that shows how to do it, maybe you can help?

Thanks,
Dejan

Comment: Did you read explanations about adaptive streaming in pytube documentation? Might be that, for some videos, you have to download images & audio separately, then post process them with ffmpeg. https://pypi.org/project/pytube/

Comment: Thanks @David, so basically I was (un)lucky that the first stream is actually progressive one and thus contained bot video and audio together, others are adaptive so I have to workout more to get it all together

Answer (score 1):

You're downloading an adaptive (DASH) stream which have audio and video split into two files. You can filter these out by adding the argument `progressive=True` to your filter method