# How can i download a YouTube video with his own sound via app was made by Python

Tags: python, tkinter, youtube, customtkinter

The Video gets download without sound

Screenshot of the app + the videos i have been downloaded:

[image: Screenshot of the app + the videos i have been downloaded]

I tried with this block of code + I used **customtkinter** and **tkinter** library

```
def download_video():
    url = entry_url.get()
    resolution = resolution_var.get()

    try:
        yt = YouTube(url)
        stream = yt.streams.filter(res=resolution).first()
        # Download the video into a specific dirrectory
        os.path.join("downloads", f"{yt.title}.mp4")
        stream.download(output_path="downloads")
    except:
        print("")
```

```
# Create a resolution combo box
resolutions = ["1080", "720p", "360p", "240p"]
resolution_var = ctk.StringVar()
resolution_combobox = ttk.Combobox(content_frame, values=resolutions, textvariable=resolution_var)
resolution_combobox.pack(pady=(10, 5))
resolution_combobox.set("1080p")
```

Comment: So what is your problem on downloading video?

Comment: The Video gets download without sound

Comment: there are undefined variables in the example code.
the question needs sufficient code for a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Comment: This [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58778492/pytube-to-download-filtered-video-and-audio-together) may help.